# Android emulator application deployment error

Tags: android, android-emulator

I have developed an application in Rhodes framework and deployed the application in an Android emulator. When I try to access the application i get the following error,

**SD card error, Application can't access the SD card while it's mounted.
Please unmount the device and stop the adb server before launching the application.**
I have tried to unmount the SD card in the emulator but I am unable to do that.

Any help will be of great use.

Thanks in advance,

Karthik.

Comment: do you have your sd card parition mounted somewhere (to move/remove files)?